# Calculating intersect area in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I Have the following code in Google Earth Engine:

```
// Add a 500 meret buffer to the gridpoints
var gridpointsBuffered = gridpoints.map(function(feature) {
 return feature.buffer(500); // 500 meter buffer
});

// Add the feature collections and buffered gridpoints to the map
Map.addLayer(gridpointsBuffered, {color: 'FF0000', opacity: 0.5}, 'Buffered Grid Points');
Map.addLayer(gridpoints, {color: 'FF0000'}, 'Original Grid Points');
Map.addLayer(water, {color: '0000FF'}, 'Water Bodies');
```

How can I calculate the intersecting area between grid point buffers and water polygons in Google Earth Engine for each buffer separately and store the area value in each buffer's properties?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a `map` to apply the following steps to each buffer:

1. Calculate the intersection of the two geometries with `ee.Feature.intersection`.
2. Calculate the area (in square meters) of the intersection with `ee.Feature.area`.
3. Store the area as a property using `ee.Feature.set`.

In code, you should be able to do something like:

```js
// Map over each buffer, calculating and setting the intersection area
var gridpointsBufferedArea = gridpointsBuffered.map(function(buffer) {
  var intersection = buffer.intersection(water);
  var area = intersection.area();
  return buffer.set("intersection_area", area);
})
```